# The import com.google.maps.android.R cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make an Android app with Google Maps feature. I have setup everything, and imported all the required libraries, etc.

But, I'm getting this annoying error, which I really don't understand what is wrong, I googled it but couldn't find any solution for this so I thought I should post here.

I'm using Android Maps Utils
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

and I'm getting this error: **The import com.google.maps.android.R cannot be resolved**

This error is coming in two files of Android Maps Utils.

1. DefaultClusterRenderer.java (Package: com.google.maps.android.clustering.view)
2. IconGenerator.java (Package: com.google.maps.android.ui)

Any help to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

adding support library will solve this problem. select your project, go to android tools and then add support library. And then your error should not show there ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Right click on Project/properties/javaBuildPath  Projects -> add library

Comment: I am getting this error as well in Android Studio.  Library is installed and app appears to work, but still have error.  How do I resolve?